# UITableView Load Cell and ObjectForKey

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem that should be quite common. I have an Array of data called `taskList` this comes from a JSON and has several user data. So far, so good. I make the first `objectForKey:@"desc"` and returns the result (Description of user) but when I try to add another objectForKey (age for example) it shows only the age :( This is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",taskList);
    cell.textLabel.text = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"];
    return cell;
    cell.textLabel.text = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"age"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you use the first `return cell;` it exits the function and no code following that is called.  What do you **want** this to do?  Show both `desc` and `age` in the same label?

Comment: In the same cell... I tried doing     `NSLog(@"%@",taskList);
    cell.textLabel.text = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"age"];
    return cell;`

Comment: are you wanting to append the two values together?  (ie "Description22"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this instead:

```
NSString *desc = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"];
NSString *age  = [[taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"age"];

cell.textLabel.text = [desc stringByAppendingString:age];
return cell;
```

Another example, which formats the string (in this case the only difference is that I'm adding a space between the two but it introduces you to a very very helpful method) (and uses the two strings that we created above):

```
NSString *textForMyLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", desc, age];
cell.textLabel.text      = textForMyLabel;
```

Or to do the same thing without the temporary variable `textForMyLabel` use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [desc stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", age];
```

Comment: Your welcome!  I added a couple more examples that will probably help you as you continue.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted, you'll never get to the 'age' portion since it will return after setting 'desc'.  Even if you fix that, you're still assigning desc and age to the same field in the cell, which isn't likely to be what you want.

Comment: That depends **entirely** on what you want to have happen.  You really haven't said.